# How to reduce padding in css?

Tags: javascript, html, css

My html code:

```
<div class="body" id="contact">
<form>
<table>
<tr>
<td><label>Name</label></td>
```

CSS:

```
  div.contact {
    float: left;
   background: url(../images/separator-light-vertical.png) repeat-y right top;
   height: 225px;
   width: 254px;
   padding: 20px 40px 0 20px;
}
```

It shows a large spacing over there, how to reduce the space between name and the text box.

[image]

Comment: should be `div#contact`

Comment: even though I add div#contact it does not show any change

Comment: where is the textbox in your code?

Comment: the above HTML code continues as <td><input type="text" name="name" id="name"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><label>Gender</label></td>

Comment: remove the table then

Comment: or put both elements in same `td`

Comment: Could you please share a JSFiddle, with **ALL** of your code? This isn't very specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`" . "` is class and
`" # "` is ID.

So you are using `<div class="body" id="contact">`

It should be:

```
#contact{
    float: left;
    background: url(../images/separator-light-vertical.png) repeat-right top;
    height: 225px;
    width: 254px;
    padding: 20px 40px 0 20px;
}
```

Update :1

Based on the screen shot, i have did this hope this works for you.

[image]

Code :

```
<div class="body" id="contact">
<form>
<table>
<tr>
<td class="firsttd"><label>Name</label></td>
<td><input type=text></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="firsttd"><label>Gender</label></td>
<td>
<input type=radio >Male
<input type=radio>Female
 </td>
  </table>
```

CSS :

```
 .firsttd{
  width:auto;
  }
 .subtd{     
 width:auto;
 }

 #contact {
float: left;
 background: url(../images/separator-light-vertical.png) repeat-y right top;
 height: 225px;
 width: 254px;
 padding: 20px 40px 0 20px;
 border:2px solid teal;
 }
```

Updated the HTML code:

[image]

Comment: its not working . Then how can I accept it as answer

Comment: yeaaa above code is start working but there is a large space between radio buttons

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
  #contact {
    float: left;
   background: url(../images/separator-light-vertical.png) repeat-y right top;
   height: 225px;
   width: 254px;
   padding: 20px 40px 0 20px;
}
```

Comment: you can remove div selector and try can u share the fiddle

Comment: html code is <div class="body" id="contact">
 
 <form>
<table>
<tr>
<td width="50%"><label>Name</label></td>
<td><input type="text" name="name" id="name"/></td>
css script is body {
 background: #211917 url(../images/bg-body.png) repeat-y center top;
 font-family: "QuattrocentoSans-Regular";
 margin: 0;
}div#contact {
 float: left;
 background: url(../images/separator-light-vertical.png) repeat-y right top;
 height: 225px;
 width: 254px;
 
}

Answer (score 0):

Since it is an `id` you can directly use the id selector in css

```
#contact{
   float: left;
   background: url(../images/separator-light-vertical.png) repeat-y right top;
   height: 225px;
   width: 254px;
   padding: 20px 40px 0 20px;
}
```

Also not when float is applied to an element it's effectively taking it out of the document flow, so adding padding to its parent won't have an effect on it.

Answer (score 0):

Give styles to the "td" tag, (remove the default padding and margin then write custom style for those properties)

Answer (score 0):

Padding you are applying is first one is for "top" second is for "right" third is for "bottom" and the last one is for "left" keeping in mind these try with reducing padding. It moves in this direction.